# How to plot random impulse train?

Tags: plotting

How to plot a random impulse train with random height and space? From the following code, I was able to get a random height graph and a random interval space graph.

```
randHeights = Mod[{RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[5, 2], 20]}, 1];
randSpace = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[5, 2]];
f[t_] := 1;

GraphicsRow[{
  ListPlot[randHeights, Filling -> Axis, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> .5],
  
  ListPlot[Table[{t, f[t]}, {t, 0, 50, randSpace}], Filling -> Axis, 
   AspectRatio -> .5]
  }]
```

You may get a different result from the one I have here, and I'm still unsure how to combine these two concepts.

[image]
 
I'm looking for a single graph that has different intervals & heights (with a maximum of 1) on every run. Any idea, anyone? Thanks for the help!

Comment: `randSpace = Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[5, 2]], 1000];` and `Sort[randSpace][[1 ;; 10]]` can easily generate negative numbers. Usually random delay is specified around a base delay and is a fraction of a base delay.

Comment: @Syed I tried to use this code, but it's not generating any graph. Is it because of the `Sort` command?

Comment: This was to show that delays could be negative too (not just zero) if a `UniformDistribution` were chosen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
n = 20;
t1 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, n];
t2 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, n];
t1 = Accumulate[t1];
dat = Transpose[{t1, t2}];
ListPlot[dat, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

Comment: Almost, but I don't want to make it overlap or have a close interval from one to another, that is why I use `NormalDistribution`

Comment: I think you can adapt this yourself

Comment: Got it, I use `RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[10, 2], n]` for one of the `t`. Thanks!

Comment:  Glad to hear this. You learn more if you do it yourself.